# Mojolicious for a school project: shall I install Nginx, Apache or Lighttpd?

Tags: apache, perl, nginx, lighttpd, mojolicious

For a school project I can pick any Framework I like to create a fairly simple website. I picked Mojolicious because I like Perl.

I'm also asked to pick among three webservers: Nginx, Apache or Lighttpd. I have used Apache in the past for a PHP school project.

I'm totally lost regarding Mojolicious. The way I understand it I could totally not use any of those webservers because I have Morbo / Hypnotoad? I still have to use a webserver anyway because it's one of the rules so which one would be simpler to configure and most efficient with Mojolicious in mind?

Thank you for any help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using apache as a proxy for hypnotoad. Works fine, since this way I can use hypnotoad to hotdeploy changes.

My configuration in apaches `sites-available` is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName myhost.example.com
    <Proxy *>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3233/ keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3233/ 
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    # debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg
    LogLevel warn 
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You may also find this link helpful:

https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Apache-deployment

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I re-read your question and built a quick lighttpd with mojolicous::lite in about 10min.
Followed a couple of quick guides.

- http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/
- https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Deploying-on-Lighttpd-with-FastCGI

If you build a simple mojolicious::lite such as:

### l_myapp.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# Documentation browser under "/perldoc"
plugin 'PODRenderer';

get '/' => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  $c->render('index');
};
app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
% layout 'default';
% title 'Welcome';
Welcome to the Mojolicious real-time web framework!

@@ layouts/default.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title><%= title %></title></head>
  <body><%= content %></body>
</html>
```

Then build a conf file pointing to your lite app.

### lightthpd.conf

```
#test
# 

server.modules = (
  "mod_fastcgi",
  "mod_cgi", 
)

server.document-root = "/var/www/html/" 
server.port = 8080 

mimetype.assign = (
  ".html" => "text/html", 
  ".txt" => "text/plain",
  ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
  ".png" => "image/png" 
)

#------------------------
#for host sub in IP address
#"port" does not seem to work so use server.port

$HTTP["host"] == "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" {
        fastcgi.server = ("/" => (( 
            "bin-path" => "/opt/web-interface/l_myapp/l_myapp.pl fastcgi",   
            "check-local" => "disable",
            "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable",
            "port" => 3000))
        )
    }
```

And at the command line:
   *lighttpd -D -f lighttpd.conf*

This should give you on the command line after trying via web page "ip address":8080

- 2014-09-26 10:58:20: (log.c.166) server started
- [Fri Sep 26 10:58:30 2014] [debug] Your secret passphrase needs to be changed!!!
- [Fri Sep 26 10:58:30 2014] [debug] GET "/".
- [Fri Sep 26 10:58:30 2014] [debug] Routing to a callback.
- [Fri Sep 26 10:58:30 2014] [debug] Rendering template "index.html.ep" from DATA section.
- [Fri Sep 26 10:58:30 2014] [debug] Rendering template "layouts/default.html.ep" from DATA section.
- [Fri Sep 26 10:58:30 2014] [debug] 200 OK (0.004694s, 213.038/s).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but I think you missed that part: "I still have to use a webserver anyway because it's one of the rules [...]"

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above but you could run hypnotoad behind an nginx reverse proxy:

http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/